# How to get UIView frame position after transform?

Tags: uiview, transform, frame

I want to get the current position of a UIView after a transform rotate has been applied to it. How can i do that ?

In the UIView doc i found this about the transform property :

> "If this property is not the identity transform, the value of the frame property is undefined and therefore should be ignored."

I tried to use center and bounds instead but the result is translated (even when no transform was applied to the rotatedView)

```
newView.center = rotatedView.center;
newView.bounds = rotatedView.bounds;
newView.transform = rotatedView.transform;
```

Can anybody help please ?

Thanks in advance, vincent.

Answer (score 5):

If you know the frame before transform, you can use CGRectApplyAffineTransform function to calculate it's value after transformation.

Comment: Please could you go into a bit more detail on how you'd use CGRectApplyAffineTransform?